# How to handle Deep Linking with Auth0-react SDK

Tags: reactjs, deep-linking, auth0

I'm using Auth0-react sdk, which is the newer version of the react-auth0-spa.js.

I'm trying to redirect the user to the original URL enter in the browser before they get redirected to the Auth0 login.

The process would be the following:

1. User enters a specific url in the browser (eg: https://example.com/products/list/items) and presses enter
2. The website redirects the user to the Auth0 domain to login
3. User enters their credential and successfully login
4. At this stage, the user should be redirected to the https://example.com/products/list/items instead of just going to https://example.com

I followed the instructions to set the SDK app from the official Auth0 [website](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#install-the-auth0-react-sdk)

Here is my code:

```
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Auth0Provider
    domain="YOUR_DOMAIN"
    clientId="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    redirectUri={window.location.origin}
    audience="YOUR_AUDIENCE_URL"
  >
    <App />
  </Auth0Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

While the documentation uses an example with a clickable button to login, I have a component which triggers the login function:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const LogIn = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loginWithRedirect()
  })

  return false;
};

export default LogIn;
```

Reading some docs, I've found `handleRedirectCallback`, which in theory should be available as a method within useAuth0.
At the moment, the above login, doesn't do the deep linking redirect and I don't see an example for the auth0-react on how to use  handleRedirectCallback.
I was wondering if someone can suggest what I can use with the React SDK.

Thanks in advance.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you're looking for, but the answer in [this](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/332#issuecomment-1044483033) question helped me with a similar problem (I got `There are no query params available for parsing.` when using this callback handler).

Instead of telling Auth0 to navigate to a `/callback` route and handle the redirection there (which caused me the `no query params` issue), the solution is to add a callback function as a `onRedirectCallback` prop to the Auth0Provider component, which will navigate to wherever you want. For example:

```
  const onRedirectCallback = appState => {
    navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname, { replace: true });
  };
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I edited my answer :)